# After commiting code in Bamboo, giving message "No failed test found. A possible compilation error occurred."

Tags: eclipse, selenium, github, bamboo

I have commited code from Eclipse and while running code in bamboo, its giving me error:

> No failed test found. A possible compilation error occurred.

In logs I am getting like this:

> cannot remove ‘package.zip’: No such file or directory Unable to
> publish artifact

I am totally clueless why its giving error after new commit. I had not changed any setting here. Before this commit, build was running on Bamboo.

Comment: You've defined an artifact which the build run did not produce.

Answer (score 0):

browse through your logs. I often download tehm locally and search for "ERROR" or similar, depends on your compiler or whatever process you are running there. If itis still unclear try to make the build output of your tool more verbose. Try to rerun the build locally your locally and make sure to clean any caches. If it succeeds there is something misaligned in the environment between your local machine and the agent. If possible try building in container (option on the job configiration) to avoid the "works on my machine" issues.

As previous commenter said: This is expected behaviour, the compilation fails, hence there is no output and no file to cleanup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).